# Why does marshaling bytes from file into struct produce Asian character when value is clearly English text in file?

Tags: c#, file, unity-game-engine

I have defined a struct in C# and am using Marshal to populate it with data from 
a file. The first attribute is populating correctly, but the second attribute is being populated with an Asian character instead of the text that is clearly in the file. Relevant content of file is (first 14 characters):

ìQ¸?DANAE_FILE

Struct defined as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct DANAE_LS_HEADER
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public float version;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public char[] ident;
}
```

Code to read file (levelData.bytes are the bytes read from the file):

```
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DANAE_LS_HEADER));
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    Marshal.Copy(levelData.bytes, 0, ptr, size);
    DANAE_LS_HEADER o = (DANAE_LS_HEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, 
      typeof(DANAE_LS_HEADER));
```

The "version" attribute on the struct is read correctly (1.44), but the "ident" attribute is read in as 䅄.

Any idea why this is and what I can do about it? I can probably link to the full file if needed.

Comment: Could you add the code where you print/process these values as a string?
It's likely an encoding issue.

Comment: The 'T' in `ByValTStr` will mean using UTF-16 by default, i.e. one character per two bytes, unless you specify [the CharSet attribute on the StructLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.charset?view=netframework-4.7.2). I don't know what the best fix is though.

Comment: You can use a site like [http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html) to determine what character you're looking at. Putting in `䅄` which has code U+4144. A bit of knowledge of old ASCII will tell you that `D` (in ASCII) is 0x44 and `A` (again) is `0x41`. So clearly whoever wrote this file wrote the text as ASCII, UTF-8 or another encoding which shares the 7-bit ASCII encoding. You need to respect that when reading the file. Ideally, find out *exactly* what encoding they used (we can guess but I've already given you two different ones)

Comment: @ReousaAsteron, I'm actually just looking at the value assigned to the attribute in the "locals" view in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

While marshalling data from Intptr we need to specify Charset as Ansi.

Try declaring struct as follows:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
struct DANAE_LS_HEADER
{
    public float version;

    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public char[] ident;
}
```

Comment: That seems likely to be the answer. I'm currently running this in a script for Unity 3D, and unfortunately the change you suggest causes Unity to crash when I try to run it. I'll need to create a project independent of Unity to try this out. Then if that works, figure out why it causes Unity to crash. Thanks.I'll reply whatever I find out.

Comment: So, I created a C# project and used the structure layout you suggested, Ramesh. However, when I hit this line in the code: int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DANAE_LS_HEADER));, I get the exception "cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed". Any ideas? Still researching myself, but have not found anything useful yet. Everything i see seems to suggest that using ByValTStr, ensuring to define the SizeConst is the correct way to go.

Comment: Actually, changing ByValTStr to ByValArray worked! Thanks!

Comment: My bad, ByValTstr would have worked if you had string data type in your structure instead of char array.